# locateonscreen try multiple image

Tags: python, pyautogui

I try to search for multiple images because sometimes they change so I made `locateonscreen` function and after 3 image tries, I get an error.

```
def locateAndClickSymbolNeonVar():
    try:
        #Locate Neon PNG
        print("locate Neon.png")
        sleep(1)
        x,y = locateCenterOnScreen("Neon.png",region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
        print("click Neon.png",(x,y))
        click(x,y)
        print("sleep(20)")
        sleep(20)
        print("CheckLinkClick..")
        CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
    except:
        try:
            #Locate Neon2 PNG
            print("SymbolNeon not found...")
            print("locate Neon2.png")
            sleep(1)
            x,y = locateCenterOnScreen("Neon2.png",region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
            print("click Neon2.png",(x,y))
            click(x,y)
            print("sleep(20)")
            sleep(20)
            print("CheckLinkClick..")
            CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
            pass
        except:
            try:
                #Locate Neon4 PNG
                print("SymbolNeon2 not found...")
                print("locate Neon4.png")
                sleep(1)
                x,y = locateCenterOnScreen("Neon4.png",region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                print("click Neon4.png",(x,y))
                click(x,y)
                print("sleep(20)")
                sleep(20)
                print("CheckLinkClick..")
                CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
                pass
            except:
                try:
                    # Locate & click Google SEA Serp type 1
                    print("SymbolNeon2 not found...")
                    print("locate        WebsiteLink.png")
                    sleep(1)
                    # old 300,300,500,720
                    x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('       WebsiteLink.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                    click(x,y)
                    print("       WebsiteLink.png clicked", x, y)
                    print("sleep(5)")
                    sleep(5)
                    CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
                    pass
                except:
            try:
                        # Locate & click Google SEA Serp type 2
            print("       WebsiteLink not found...")
            print("locate        WebsiteLinkName.png")
            sleep(1)
            # old 300,300,500,720
            x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('       WebsiteLinkName.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
            click(x,y)
            print("       WebsiteLinkName.png clicked", x, y)
            print("sleep(5)")
            sleep(5)
            CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
            pass
            except:
            try:
                # Locate & click Google SEA Serp type 3
                print("       WebsiteLinkName not found...")
                print("locate        WebsiteLinkIcon.png")
                sleep(1)
                # old 300,300,500,720
                x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('       WebsiteLinkIcon.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                click(x,y)
                print("       WebsiteLinkIcon.png clicked", x, y)
                print("sleep(5)")
                sleep(5)
                CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
                pass
            except:
                try:
                                # Locate & click Google SEA Serp type 4
                                print("       WebsiteLinkIcon not found...")
                                print("locate        WebsiteSecondLinkandIcon.png")
                                sleep(1)
                                # old 300,300,500,720
                                x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('       WebsiteSecondLinkandIcon.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                                click(x,y)
                                print("       WebsiteSecondLinkandIcon.png clicked", x, y)
                                print("sleep(4)")
                                sleep(5)
                                CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
                                pass
                except:
                try:
                                    #Locate Neon3 PNG
                                    print("       WebsiteSecondLinkandIcon not found...")
                    print("locate Neon3.png")
                    sleep(1)
                    # old 300,300,500,720
                    x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('Neon3.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                    click(x,y)
                    print("Neon3.png clicked", x, y)
                    print("sleep(5)")
                    sleep(5)
                    CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
                    pass
                except:
                    try:
                    #Locate Neon5 PNG
                    print("SymbolNeon3 not found...")
                    print("locate Neon5.png")
                    sleep(1)
                    x,y = locateCenterOnScreen('Neon5.png',region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
                    click(x,y)
                    print("Neon5.png clicked", x, y)
                    print("sleep(5)")
                    sleep(5)
                    CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
    except:
    print("Neon5.png not found")
    pass
```

This is the function but it works only till `type1`, then I get inconsistent use of tabs. I don't know why, and maybe there is a better way to search with multi images. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: which error are you trying to except?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate through every .png images in a folder in order and click on them if they are found:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time


def locateAndClickSymbolNeonVar():
    # folder directory of where the .png files are
    directory = r"PATH_TO_FOLDER"
    # iterate through every .png images in a folder (Neon.png, Neon1.png, Neon2.png ect.)
    for images in os.listdir(directory):
        if images.endswith(".png"):
            # Locate on screen the current image
            time.sleep(2)
            coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(images)
            # if locateOnScreen is not returning None
            # (locateOnScreen will return none if nothing is found on the screen)
            if coordinates is not None:
                # click on x,y of the image located on the screen
                pyautogui.click(coordinates)


locateAndClickSymbolNeonVar()
```

Comment: coordinates = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(images, region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)   should  this  work  ????  alsow i  use time sleep were can  i put it in ???

Comment: at the moment  it  is not  working  i  get expected  an idented  block

Comment: it works with this code: but only with new  py not inside my script

Comment: you need to indent it based on your code, i will edit my answer

Comment: that  is  working but i have a def CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl() this is checking things after each search for image. so the try locate an image if it  found  click it if not make the def CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl() need to implement this alsow

Comment: try:
            #Locate Neon2 PNG
            print("SymbolNeon not found...")
            print("locate Neon2.png")
            sleep(1)
            x,y = locateCenterOnScreen("Neon2.png",region=(10,180,920,830), confidence=0.8)
            print("click Neon2.png",(x,y))
            click(x,y)
            print("sleep(20)")
            sleep(20)
            print("CheckLinkClick..")
            CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()

Comment: what's the code inside the CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl? You didn't include that in your post. I'm also not understanding what you want to do

Comment: which error are you even trying to except? Keep in mind that if a image is not found on the screen Pyautogui will return None and not a exception

Comment: ### Program exeption handling / restart after exeption###
run = 1
while run == 1:
    try:
        Program()
    except Exception as ex:
            print("Exeption", ex)
            sleep(2)
            CurlExeptionErrorAccours()
            print("Sleep to continue sec 600")
            sleep(600)
            continue

this  is not  from me but i think this is what the programm do with eexeption. i  really dont know but that error exception  i havent done by my self, code is from someone else i only added some things

Comment: i look for images at the time thee script is scrowlng insidee google and if it found image it clicks if not test next one if all not shown i got a curl to telegram

Comment: this is inside the def CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl():
     if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(ExtensionIconStatusRedX, ExtensionIconStatusRedY, (redtimerR ,redtimmerG , redtimerB), tolerance = 30) == False:
         print("RedTimerCorner Color not found - first check")
         randomsec = (random.randint(10,15))
         sleep(randomsec)
         if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(ExtensionIconStatusRedX, ExtensionIconStatusRedY, (redtimerR ,redtimmerG , redtimerB), tolerance = 30) == False:

Comment: print("RedTimerCorner Color not found - second check")
             randomsec = (random.randint(600,615))
             CurlLinkClickFailed()
             sleep(randomsec)
             AllTabCloseTrigger()
         else:
             print("RedTimerCorner Color found - after second check")
             SiteVisitTimerCheck()
             pass
     else:
         print("RedTimerCorner Color found - after first check")
         SiteVisitTimerCheck()

Comment: sorry the def was to long for comment i dont know how i can make this better

Comment: Again, let's logically think about this: which exception are you trying to except? I do not have the full code but i'm almost 100% sure it will not throw any exceptions (locateOnScreen will return None if nothing is found and PixelMatching will return either True or False). Also why would you even want to restart your script after a exception?

Comment: is it better now? i  search for words  inside google and let mouse pushing results down if the function find one of the image in folder it click on it then i let check a ring bell inside browser that apears for some  seconds  if it go away it  close  all tabs or write me a massage or do  some  other task

Comment: i  realy  dont know why i do this. i only use it becorse it  were in the code bevore and i only use this again its a code from an old github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250324/discussion-between-gianpi-and-bill-sian).

Comment: this to defs only do: look for images inside google tab click on it if you found one next def is checkng a ring bell check for the color if it red wait if it disapear go back to ... and make the same thing again --> search a phrase look for image click on it ---> wait till the time is disapear and do again ......

Answer (score 0):

i get a Exeption Failed to read GoogleSEAserpWebsiteLink.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
Curl ExeptionErrorAccours 2023-01-10 22:37:38.637558

i dont know why but the png file is inside the right folder here is my cod

```
#Locate & click one of four different serp Neon PNG´s (screenshoted from google search sequence)
def locateAndClickSymbolNeonVar():
    # folder directory of where the .png files are
    directory = r"scr\image\NeonandSerp"
    # iterate through every .png images in a folder (Neon.png, Neon1.png, Neon2.png ect.)
    for images in os.listdir(directory):
        if images.endswith(".png"):
            # Locate on screen the current image
            time.sleep(2)
            coordinates = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(images)
            # if locateOnScreen is not returning None
            # (locateOnScreen will return none if nothing is found on the screen)
        if coordinates is not None:
            print("found neon")
            click(coordinates)
            CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
        else:
            print("not found neon")
            CheckLinkClickFailedTrueAndCurl()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i allways get 

i get a Exeption Failed to read GoogleSEAserpWebsiteLink.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Comment: i try this on 3 mini pcs and my homepc  the GoogleSEAserpWebsiteLink.png is the first image inside the folder so i dont know why this happens

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33603556)